# JSONObject to ArrayList?

Tags: android

I have created a JSON object like this:

```
static ArrayList<item> list = new ArrayList<item>();
static {

        item dessertsItem1 = new item("name","address", "id","phone number");
        item dessertsItem2 = new item("name","address", "id","phone number");
        item dessertsItem3 = new item("name","address", "id","phone number");
}

                list.add(dessertsItem1);
        list.add(dessertsItem2);
        list.add(dessertsItem3);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parse();

    }

    private void parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
            for (item items : list) {

                JSONObject productObj = new JSONObject();
                productObj.put("ItemName", items.getName());
                productObj.put("ItemId", items.getId());
                productObj.put("ItemDescription", items.getDescription());
                productObj.put("ItemPrice", items.getPrice());

                Log.d("RESPONSE OBJECTS>", "the response objects are"
                        + responseObj + "\n" + productObj);
                jarray.put(productObj);
                Log.d("%%%%", "the json array is " + jarray);

            }

            responseObj.put("Desserts", jarray);
}
```

How do I convert the JSONObject to an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it.
[Example 1](http://laurentszyster.be/less4j/javadoc/org/less4j/JSON.html)
[Example 2](http://csm2kh.blogspot.com/2008/07/json-array-list-json.html)